# YII, Form in View page, AJAX update

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I have a CListView in which I added a form to upload an image. This way each item has its own fileupload..

The form has a ajaxLink that posts the request. I added 'foto' to the accessRule. My controller is reached by the request, there is no error. The files only isn't posted and the location not saved in my database.

I think it cannot get the instance 'image' of the uploadfile, because of the form in the view. Am I right and how can I fix this?

CListView _view:

```
<div class="view">
   <!--more content and..-->
   <?php        
   $model=new Nieuws;
   echo $this->renderPartial('_plaatje', array('model'=>$model, 'itemId'=>$data->id)); ?>
</div>
```

Form:

```
    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'plaatjes-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ),
)); ?>


    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'pad'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'image'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'pad'); ?>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'ondertitel'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'ondertitel',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'ondertitel'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'url'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'url',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'url'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Model:

```
class Nieuws extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $image;
    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'nieuws';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('titel, tekst, verwijderd', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('foto', 'length', 'max'=>100),
            array('datum, verwijderDatum', 'safe'),
            array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'on'=>'foto'),
            array('image', 'length', 'max'=>255, 'on'=>'foto'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, titel, datum, tekst, foto, verwijderd, verwijderDatum', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function actionFoto($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    if(isset($_POST['Foto']))
    {
        $model->foto=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
        if($model->save())
        {
            $model->foto->saveAs('uploads/');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the name of your controller? Do you have any rules in your url manager? Your ajax should point to <controller>/<action> to reach it.

Comment: controller is NieuwsController. I don't have rules in my url manager. 
When I monitor the ajax request it goes to: index.php?r=nieuws/foto&id=22 with status 200 ok.

Comment: If your controller is `Nieuws` and your action is `foto` than your ajax request should point to `/nieuws/foto`.

Comment: hmm, ok, none of my ajax request didn't work anymore and I found an error in my Model. So I'll update the above, to make everything understandable again. It reaches my action right now, but it seems to be unable to make the instance of my fileupload.

Comment: I do not know this rule `array('image', 'length', 'max'=>255, 'on'=>'foto')`. Are you sure that works? Since you do not get any php error it might be one of your rules that doesn't match? Maybe you attach a message to them and look what gets fired.

Comment: you're right, I don't need that rule. It's the one that 'foto' allready does. So if I do: 
$model->foto = 'sdffff';$model->save(); 
It works. If I do that before he writes the uploadfile instance to the model->foto, the result is empty. So the uploaded file is apparently empty... But I don't know why it is ;-) Can that still be a rule?

Comment: Check your rules with a var_dump($model->validate()); before saving in controller. It should give you info on validation errors and what they are.

Comment: yes, that's it. It didn't validate, so the post wasn't finished. Thanks!